# Can you use a XML-RPC data source for Adobe Flex applications?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, xml-rpc

Can an XML-RPC call be made and the resulting XML response be utilized by Adobe's Flex?

Would Flex be better served by a non-XML response and if so what format?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at the [as3-rpclib](http://code.google.com/p/as3-rpclib/) project if you want to use XML-RPC.

The Flex standard libraries have SOAP support (in [`mx.rpc.soap`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/soap/package-detail.html)) so that's an alternative as well. The most effective protocol, though, is [AMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format), support for which is also included with Flex (see [`mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/rpc/remoting/RemoteObject.html)) ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format) has links to some server-side AMF libraries).